# MySQL no index are used, but Handler_read_key increase

Tags: mysql, indexing

I've a table

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    id    INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
  , data  VARCHAR(32)
  , ts    TIMESTAMP
  , INDEX (data)
);
```

with some test data.

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES
  (NULL, 'abc', '2018-01-18 00:00:01'), (NULL, 'abc', '2018-01-18 00:00:02'),
  (NULL, 'abd', '2018-01-18 00:00:03'), (NULL, 'acd', '2018-01-18 00:00:04'),
  (NULL, 'def', '2018-01-18 00:00:05'), (NULL, 'pqr', '2018-01-18 00:00:06'),
  (NULL, 'stu', '2018-01-18 00:00:07'), (NULL, 'vwx', '2018-01-18 00:00:08'),
  (NULL, 'yza', '2018-01-18 00:00:09'), (NULL, 'def', '2018-01-18 00:00:10');
```

As per [MySQL 5.7 Reference Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Handler_read_key)

> Handler_read_key
>
> The number of requests to read a row based on a key. If this value is high, it is a good indication that your tables are properly indexed for your queries.

The value of `Handler_read_key` will increase only when reading a row based on a key.
However, when I run sql

```
FLUSH STATUS ;
SELECT * FROM test WHERE ts = '2018-01-18 00:00:01';
SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Handler_read%';
```

There's no index on column `ts`, but both `Handler_read_first` and `Handler_read_key` are increased. Which is inconsistent with the above document.

So, why?

Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Why is this a problem? I'm not sure what you're concerned about.

Comment: @tadman Added more description.

Comment: I'm still not sure *why* you think this is an issue. It's probably an artifact of how MySQL works internally.

Comment: InnoDB-Tables are, in contrast to MyISAM-tables, based on index structures. So technically, even a full table scan on such a table should count as an index access and should increase the value by 1. But 1 is generally not considered a very high number, so it would not contradict the information in the manual. If you experience a different behaviour, please add your numbers to your question. Also check your value for "Handler_read_rnd_next" (and read the manual entry for that), and test with MyISAM-tables.

Comment: To better explain things, please provide the tablesize (in rows), and the output of `SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';`  And which Engine are you using.